# ArrayList inside TableCell JavaFX

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, tableview

I want to accomplish something like this with JavaFX.
An article can have one or more sizes (with it respective stock) and size is present in zero or more articles.

[image: Table]

I have Article class

```
public class Article {
    private IntegerProperty id;
    private StringProperty code;
    private StringProperty name;
    private StringProperty description;
    private ObservableList<Category> categories;
    private ObservableList<ArticleStockInfo> stockInfo;
    private Brand brand;
    private FloatProperty price;
    private BooleanProperty checked;

    //Constructor, methods
    ...
}
```

I also have ArticleStockInfo

```
public class ArticleStockInfo {
    private Size size;
    private IntegerProperty stock;

    //Constructor, methods
    ...
}
```

Now I'm showing articles in a TableView with some TableColumns

```
@FXML private TableView<Article> articlesTable;
@FXML private TableColumn<Article, Number> articlesTableIdColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<Article, Number> articlesTablePriceColumn;
```

And that's how I'm filling the table

```
articles = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ArticlesMethods.getAllArticles());
filteredArticle = new FilteredList<>(articles, p -> true);
SortedList<Article> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredArticle); sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(articlesTable.comparatorProperty());
//Add sortedItems to the TableView
articlesTable.setItems(sortedData);
```